# How much should a computer science undergrad charge for web design/development services, when just starting out?

Tags: website-design, freelance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What price should I charge for design services?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services)

I'm a computer science undergraduate and have recently successfully applied for a web-design job but have a few questions.

Before a contract is drawn up I have a discussion scheduled to discuss salary and other details, but I'm not really sure how much to ask for?

- I'm 18
- I'm currently in full-time study so will be working part-time, therefore paid by hour - roughly 10-15 hours a week
- The majority of the work will be graphic design with PHP/ASP coding every now and again.
- My main reason for this job is to gain some real-world experience in the hope of actually getting a decent, related, job when I graduate.

They want me to officially start work after Easter but however they also want me to work on a small re-design over the Easter holidays (that's fine with me) in order to understand the company better, start to get familiar with their processes and show them what I'm capable of.

However, they want me to quote for this but again, not sure what to charge. I've done websites for friends/friends of friends in the past but charged fairly low rates(£50-£100 for some fairly advanced stuff, i.e. Paypal IPN etc).

The website I must re-design is a fairly simple, static, website with just a few pages.

Comment: Too lazy to look it up right now, but I'm sure either this site or webmasters already has a question on pricing. Basically, it depends on too many factors to be answerable: region, type of project/work, client size/revenue, client's industry, additional benefits (including things like experience/referrals, which aren't part of the contract), and your own level of experience and skill. There are entire books dedicated to the art of pricing, so it's not really an appropriate question for SE.

Comment: For freelance/per job pricing, I answered with a formula here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-to-design-business-cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have applied for a web design job ... but it sounds like you are quoting in by project?  Why not just set up an hourly rate with them, and then just give them a rough estimate of hours you expect it to take?

Right now with limited experience - getting experience should be your primary concern. So setup a reasonable hourly contracting rate and work from that.

I wouldn't call it 'a job' if you are fix bidding projects to them. They are then just 'a client' as you are a freelancer / independent contractor.

Why not just try to get them to employ you at a reasonable hourly rate. They get a good deal on a developer, you get money and great experience.

12 years ago when I was starting out I worked for $12/hr and it gave me the experience I needed to then charge $125+/hr now.  Consider it an investment in yourself at this point. Have fun, make a little money but get the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The Short answer.... whatever you feel you can get away with.

The longer answer... You need to figure your overhead and minimum wage and divide that by working hours in the year to come up with an hourly rate. Then you can use the hourly rate to calculate per project costs.

What one person charges will **NEVER** let you know what you should be charging. It may give you a general idea if you have the *exact* same experience and proficiency as someone else, but other pricing should really never be seen as a guideline but more as a ballpark. Anyone can state "I charge $XXX.XX per hour" That really is meaningless because your individual skills, experience, region, and client base will most certainly be different. Never trust number like that.

[Check this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-to-design-business-cards) here are graphicdesign.stackexchange for some really good calculations regarding general pricing.