# What is a good systematic approach to increasing the rates I charge?

Tags: client-relations, freelance

In the past year, I have been getting more and more freelance projects along with my work as a graphic design teacher. I've been working in the graphic design field 10+ years. Because these contracts are not my main revenue, I have not been too concerned with raising my fees and I'm now facing the situation where I should be outsourcing some of my work to collaborators (either because I can't keep up or because I want to take on more teaching work temporarily) but I am also not charging enough to afford them. So I am thinking of hiking my rates but I don't want to scare the clients away.

Just to put some hypothetical numbers and give more context, if I charge 5$/hour on a project and take 5 hours to finish it but I'm too busy and I need to hire someone who charges me 2$/hour but takes 15 hours to do the same (and I still need to charge an hour for checking out their work and giving them feedback), things just don't add up.

I use flat rates most of the time but for some small things like corrections or when I am working for agencies, I'll charge an hourly rate and this is where the hike is likely to show more.

I know raising gradually is likely to be what will be recommended but how often and how incremental is gradual?

Also, do you have a systematic approach to raising your own rates? (following cost of life, as you acquire new skills, etc.).

Do you email all your clients or wait for a new project to come in?

Do you raise a certain % each year? When do you consider stopping to raise?

Unsure if this question belongs here or in the freelance SE but I'm mostly interested in what fellow graphic designers would have to say.

Answer (score 6):

In reality, as a designer freelancing, my hourly rates are really unimportant beyond what I need to cover any overhead. Truth be told if I stuck strictly to the standard (overhead + 20% profit) I'd be barely surviving. I have very little overhead.

A more realistic approach to pricing is **value based pricing**. See [THIS QUESTION](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18142/which-is-a-better-design-pricing-model?rq=1) for a few answers on *how* to price. Which is related to your question.

Sure I have an hourly rate I can tell clients. However it's largely unrealistic. If a client insists upon knowing an hourly rate I adjust project time to meet my pricing.

I detest bidding anything based on an hourly rate. I **much prefer** per-project bids. It prevents any surprises the client may experience when invoices are sent and it's solely up to me to ensure I'm bidding enough to cover my living. Once you get into "time" bids or hourly bidding you are leaving it up to the client to estimate how much time it will take you to complete something. That's not a viable situation for me. I don't work at the same rate that Bill, Bob, Jane, and Tom do.. I work at my own rate. So there's no possible way the client could *ever* know how long something truly takes me to complete.

For example (similar to your question), if a client *insists* on knowing my hourly rate I tell them $10/hr. Then they ask how long will it take to complete [Y]. I tell the client it'll take 5 hours. So, I get the work for $50 and the client is happy. Now does the client need to know that I can actually complete the project in 30 minutes of pushing a mouse around? Hell no! I spent years and years and years learning my trade so that I *can* only spend 30 minutes pushing the mouse. What about the creative phase where I'm considering *how* to design things or choosing an appropriate color palette, or typeface, or researching competitors so I can ensure my creative is correct? Or the years I've spend honing my sense of aesthetics. All that can not be quantified. Your rate should **never** be restricted to *only* the time you touch a mouse. It's simply wrong to penalize yourself due to experience.

If the same client simply asked me "How much to complete this?" I'd simply state $50.

True hourly return = $5, Added value return = $50.

You can often tell a client a project costs $5,000 and they are fine with it. But if you tell the *same client* the *same project* will take 20 hours and your hourly rate is $250 (equalling $5,000) they'll almost all fake a seizure.

### How I raise rates.....

I simply bid higher on new projects. If last month I would bid $X to complete something, this month I bid ($x + 10%). Thus increasing my return on the same project by an additional 10%.

If a client asks about the price difference, I explain that rates have increased due to rising costs of living and overhead. If pushed, I will at times stick to previous rates for the **first** project for an **existing client** immediately after I've raised rates. But **only** the first project.

### For existing, ongoing projects....

If, for example, I have a client who I've been doing virtually the same thing for, repeatedly, and pricing has always been the same. i.e. Project Y costs a flat fee of $10. And it cost $10 every time the client has requested it over a period of months or even years. At that point, I **will** send an email to inform the client of an increase. Usually I send it with a proof or final file for the last request of the project. Something along the lines of:

> Hi [client],
>
> I just wanted to make you aware that work on [project], which has customarily incurred a fee of [$x], will be increasing to a fee of [new $x] in the future.
>
> [project] I'm currently completing will be billed at the previous rate of [$x], but I wanted you to be aware of the increase moving forward.
>
> I realize I've completed [project] for the [$x] for several [months/years/weeks] but it has become necessary to increase the fee to [new $x] in order to offset business overhead and the rising costs of living.
>
> I hope you understand and I'm always available to discuss the matter if you'd like.
>
> Thanks!

Then I simply invoice the new cost in the future.

### As for when to raise pricing....

I find a schedule for price increases is both unmanageable and generally unsatisfactory. If I set a schedule to raise rates every year, what about when I'm experiencing a low in work in the previous quarter? Raising rates certainly will not help that situation. What if it's mid-year and there's no possible way I can complete all the work I'm getting? Should I wait 6 months to increase rates? Of course not. I need to alleviate the cacophony of requests now, not next year. I need to raise rates immediately.

**My rates are dependent upon my general workload.** In any given month I may have more or less work, I know that each week I customarily get so many new projects, edits to previous projects, and requests for quotes. I can tell in a matter of a couple weeks if things are slowing down or loading up. However, I don't react immediately to these fluctuations. Weekly fluctuations can happen, but if I start seeing a trend over several weeks, I look closer.

For example, FEB 2013 and the first couple weeks of MAR 2013 were very busy for me. Busier than I could handle without working 16-18 days 7 days a week. So I raised rates on any new project bids mid March. Oct-Dec of 2013 were even *more* busy for me. So I raised rates *again* in Dec 2013. So far, 2014 has been more along the lines of my preferred workload - steady and stable without being overwhelmed for more than a day or two.So I'll leave pricing as it stands until I feel overwhelmed again.

There's an old adage which states *"If you get every project you bid on, your rates are too low."* I expect to not get every project I'm requested to quote. Sometimes *that* takes a bit of getting used to -- hearing, "Sorry, you cost too much." and not altering your rates and being comfortable knowing more work will come in spite of losing that particular project.

- If you are getting enough work to keep you stable and consistent, without feeling overwhelmed or too busy, chances are your pricing is good where it's at.
- If you are getting **more work** than you can handle or are getting more work than you actually want, then it's time to increase your rates to weed out some of the clients unwilling to pay higher rates.
- If you are getting **less work** than you need to survive, it may be time to think about *lowering* your rates in order to acquire smaller clients.

**EDIT:**
I should add that if I have a client who *insists* on paying hourly, I do track the hours faithfully and invoice for only that fee without any value adjustment. These types of jobs for me are customarily edits to previous projects. In that sense, an hourly-based price structure makes the most logical sense. Because I'm not reinventing creative, I'm often merely editing text, there's no "value" in any edits from my perspective. Therefore hourly rates for editing save the client money and pretty much *are* just the time pushing a mouse around. It would be unethical to take on an hourly-based edit/project and then fabricate hours.

I'm always as transparent as I can be with pricing for my clients. I don't ever want any client to feel I'm being less than ethical with pricing. Sometimes my pricing means I don't get work, but in most cases its not an issue. In fact, in most cases, clients actually prefer knowing *exactly* what something will cost before I start working - that's often not possible via strictly hourly-based pricing due to unforeseen client demands. With value-based pricing I have a little wiggle-room to allow some *minor* changes to the scope of a project without being in a position where I *must* adjust pricing for any small addition. This flexibility is seen as beneficial to the client. They know that "Oh, can we change that to blue instead?" isn't going to cost them another $10.

Comment: I like your take on reconsidering the amount of time since the client doesn't know. Part of my demise is definitely my speed. It could get more complicated to manage if the client gives a tight deadline but could be justified with a rush fee.

Comment: I do use rush fees as well. Not always due to tight deadlines themselves, but more often due to a tight deadline in addition to existing commitments. If I need to push Client A's project back a day so I can complete the (rush) project for Client B, then it means I'll have to work more hours and faster to complete both projects. It's only fair that Client B have additional costs due to their request. If I have nothing going on and Client B asks for a rush project, I may or may not waive any rush fee.

Comment: I do see a problem with legal ramifications though, although I don't see how a client could prove how much time you've put on X or Y. But you're right in saying clients get a seizure if they see a certain rate, this is part of the problem I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What legal ramifications? If Billy Joe Jim Bob's Auto Repair tells you it'll take 15 days to fix your car for $400, but they get repaired in 5 days and charge you $400... does anyone complain? Does anyone ask for a lower rate since it only took 1/3 the estimated time? Of course not.

Comment: Time to complete is **not** time pushing a mouse around. There's often a creative phase which can not be quantified, along with any exploratory phase, and then there's the years of experience you may have. If every designer priced only for when they had their hand on a mouse the industry would be dead long ago.

Comment: I agree with you on that last comment, but I also don't see how it doesn't fit into [overcharging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overcharge), specifically the 4th paragraph (too long, couldn't paste). The rules don't seem clear on it.

Comment: Your'e freelancing.. how could there possibly be any collusion leading to overcharging? Do you have a twin which has your exact skillset and experience?  Are you a member of a group of designers who have agreed to fix rates for specific projects at a specific dollar amount? Your'e thinking *way* too much about this.

Comment: I ask Painter A how much to paint my house, he says $50. I ask Painter B how much, he says $48.50. I ask Painter C, he says $150. I ask why the difference, it's the same house. Painter C has 30 years experience, Painter A has 5 years experience, and Painter B has 2 years experience. Is there any overcharging there? No. It's a free market system and any service industry is allowed to charge whatever they want for their service. It's entirely up to the customer to choose to pay that rate or not. There's no such thing as "Overcharging" for a service, You can only "overcharge" for goods.

Comment: You **can't** overcharge for creative services. There is no such thing. The lawyer example is different, it's not creative. You could only overcharge by doing something like purchasing a stock photo for $5 and charging the client $100 for that same photo. *That may be a legal issue.* But you are free to price your *service* however you wish to price it.

Comment: Maybe I did not get my point across so well, I was talking about overcharging related to manipulating time values (i.e. if you tell the client you will do something for 10$/hour and that it will take you 2 hours but it really took you 30 minutes). I agree it doesn't apply with flat fees.

Comment: It's not overcharging. If I charge $100 for the project, it doesn't matter if I get their via 10 hrs at $10 per, 5 hrs at $20 per, or 1 hr at $100 per. It's still $100. The only difference is the explanation to the client so they digest it in a more acceptable manner. Again, this is what value-based pricing is and this is how most successful designers I know price their work. If you're of mind to track every single second and invoice for time spent without variation, then you're going to need high hourly rates to ever get ahead. And high hrly rates will kill client base.

Comment: These may be helpful to you: http://blog.priceintelligently.com/blog/bid/162160/Value-Based-Pricing-101-The-Necessities-and-Your-Pricing-Strategy -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-based_pricing -- http://speckyboy.com/2013/08/29/value-based-pricing/ -- Overall it sounds as though you're just stuck in the "punching a timecard" mentality. You need to break free of that.

Answer (score 0):

Double your rates every time you get the urge. At least once per year. It will help you leapfrog out of bad situations and into more interesting ones. And force you to improve significantly each year because you know you're going to double your rates at least once a year.

---

### :::::::::: EDIT ::::::::::

Clearly this is more controversial and edgy than most people are accustomed to. But if you have some talent, much persistence, a high intellect, challenge yourself to learn and improve - then your designs skills will improve at an exponential rate relative to the average person. And this means you are going to either be massively over servicing your local customers, or progressively climbing to a new altitude each year.

This is not for everyone, obviously. But if you have the pre-requisites this is utterly doable. At some point you won't be able to double your rates every year, diminishing returns will hit eventually. But that's a lot further off than you might imagine if you've got some of the prerequisites to keep at improvement and keep communicating with your clients, past and present, and future.

People that look for talent will see you coming, they will recognise your trajectory and mark you for future attention. This is no different than the path to becoming a great athlete, in this sense. But it's very different in another sense... in that you always control your destiny until you run of momentum, persistence, patience, communication skills, intellect and talent. Everyone has a ceiling on their impact on the world.

But what I'm suggestion is a systematic approach to not only improve your pay rate, but also the kinds of clients you're working for. You WILL be leaving clients behind. You must always TRY to part amicably (it won't always be possible) despite this increase being their first consideration. Explain to them how far you've come during the time you've been their designer. Show them the improvement curve. It will be plainly visible. They'll understand that you've become out of their reach. That it's in your best interests to move on.

Everyone in business has faced skill issues. Both an inability to attain sufficiently skilled people and also the loss of those that improve past their financial reach. It happens in every single industry. No business person worth dealing with is unaware of these eventualities. They will wish you the best, and aspire to find the money to hire you once again, to benefit from your designs and what they can do for their business.

And you must remember this. Design is about assisting business. The better you become at design the bigger the businesses you are able to assist in ever bigger ways. So the growth in income IS exponential if you're up to the challenge to increasingly assist in ever more influential ways.

Graphic Design can be production line work, like putting cars together if you want. Or it can be about changing the world through the brands and products, services and people you assist to put on their best image and identity.

Besides, doubling your price is nowhere near as brutal as telling someone you're too busy for them ;)

Comment: I think you are advocating a process for someone who wants to start a business which is not my case. I am only considering hiring collaborators to gain some flexibility on my workload. The precarity involved with starting a teaching career is what's making me ask my question and not corporate ambitions.

Comment: Cleaning comments as the edit clarifies the answer. You can continue the discussion [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13213/discussion-between-confused-and-gramps).

Comment: @Emilie should the value of your work differ based on whether you want to start a company vs. not?

Comment: It's a good question, I have also been pondering this and I can see it both ways: charging less because I'm less available in general (not always reachable on regular business hours) and that could be detrimental to the client (although I usually end up making it up by working more weekly hours anyways!) or charging more because it's a side revenue and I don't "have" to do it.