# How to know how much to charge for an animation?

Tags: animation, video

I'm a robotics engineer who just joined the world of video animations, I just finished my first project and I have no idea if I charged the fair amount for it. I would like to know how to put prices on this kind of work, is it per hour worked on it? is it per type of animations made? or how?

This is the video I just made.

https://vimeo.com/93598964

Comment: It depends heavily on the type animation. Character animation si quite different from the kind of hide lines/ scale and move animations your doing.

Comment: And how to know how much to charge for them?

Comment: Setting a price is a bit mystical, basically you should either ask as much as your client can pay, or scale your work to what they are paying. Charging by the hour is not a good idea because then a better artist should charge less. But the rule i used to operate with back in the day was 100 euros per final second.

Comment: Per second???? Woah that is a lot, are you sure is per second? but what kind of work did you do for that price/time ?

Comment: yes per second. Character animation at about 2- 6 final seconds per day. This offcourse includes a lot of other stuff such as storyboarding, inking, shading,metings with client, materials, rent... Times have changed since then tough. Not that your anim is that expensive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is a better design pricing model?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18142/which-is-a-better-design-pricing-model)

Comment: My stock answer: You charge at least enough to make a living http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services

Comment: @joojaa there's nothing mystical about it. It's math. While you may have 'billed' per second, ultimately you *were* charging for the hours you were working--you just translated the hours you were working into finished animation seconds.

Comment: @DA01 math part is figuring my  cost, figuring out the added value for the customer is unknown. This is why stockmarkets exist because we dont know. Anyway negotiating price for animation is a huge hustle. Ps 100 euros per second is sweatshop like production salary over here :)

Comment: @joojaa oh for sure, 'added value' is above and beyond the math part. I agree with that.

Comment: Considering you've plagiarized the characters from PhDComics, I would not have sold it at all...

Answer (score 3):

Pricing should always be a reflection of:

1. Cost of living (how much do you need to earn to live)
2. The actual time spent working on the project
3. Cost of doing business - like your computers, electricity, education and training, office space, etc.
4. Any regulatory/tax costs that you are responsible for

Putting it all together you should end up with a good pricing structure that reflects the reality of the costs of your time and resources to accomplish a given work.

Over time you'll continue to tweak and improve your pricing structure (and your project estimation skills) until it is second nature and fairly accurate for any given project.

In your particular case I would suggest charging for the hours spent, broken down into 1/4 or 1/2 hour segments.