# I find it impossible to quote for a logo design as I never know how long it will take? Any tips I can accurately quote?

Tags: logo, pricing

I am able to quote for most design tasks (brochure, business cards, leaflets etc) relatively easily, as I have a rough idea of how long I think these will take. But when it comes to designing a logo, I never know how much to quote as every logo I design either I can create in 30minutes or it can take weeks. I think this for me is because with a logo design I am starting from scratch, a blank canvas. Wherewith other tasks, I always have a branding concept to guide me.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a pricing structure? How do you quote for logos designs?

Comment: [A good article which may be helpful](https://creative-boost.com/pricing-mistakes/) Particularly #2

Comment: @Scott: how can #2 apply here? This question is about time, not about price, if I get that right.

Comment: @ThomasWeller How can an article which explains why "Charging *Hourly* for Creative Work" is a bad thing **not** be relatable here??? Please **read** #2. It even *specifically* mentions logo design as an example.

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18142/which-is-a-better-design-pricing-model

Comment: @Scott: because OP has not mentioned that he is billing hourly. Maybe he charges a fixed price like $1000, which is not much if needs 3 weeks, but quite good if he needs 30 minutes.

Comment: >> *I am able to quote for ...* <<< and >>> *...have a rough idea of how long I think these will take* <<< Guess I see more pricing question here than you do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What price should I charge for design services?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services)

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts:

> I think this for me is because with a logo design I am starting from scratch, a blank canvas

That is the main problem. So, solve it.

**I.** Prepare a **good interview with the client**. Some possible questions in random order:

- What colors identify your brand?
- An animal can identify a characteristic of your brand, speed, force, etc. Would you like one?
- Do you like text-only logos?
- Do you want an abstract logo?
- A logo that describes the process your brand solves?
- Do you have a rough idea of what do you want?
- What is the meaning of the name?

In some cases, you can explore with the client some infographic showing how different brands approach the logo.

---

**II.** Then you need to make specific revisions:

- In general terms, do you like the idea?
- What you do not like, the style, the abstraction level, the font.

---

No. A logo should not take weeks.

There is a game where you can "guess" what object is another person thinking about in 20 questions or less. Some example:

- Q1. Are you thinking in an inanimated or a live object?
- A. Inanimated.
- Q2. Is it natural or artificial, man-made?
- A. Artificial.
- Q3. Is it big or small, can I hold it with my hand, or carry it at all?
- A. Small
- Q4. Is it electronic, electric, or nonelectric at all?
- A. Non-electric

As you can see the point is reducing the options in half, this means the reduction of possibilities is logarithmic, or "inverse exponential". Do that using wisley the questions, and on your revisions.

---

This does not mean that the client is designing the logo. Probably it is up to you to make these decisions based on your expertise. But again, you need to reduce the scope of possibilities, landing the ideas, then landing the execution.