# Package Pricing

Tags: logo

We had a client that needed the following design set **without printing**:

- Logo
- business card
- letterhead
- sticker
- envelope
- brochure
- a 3*5m vinyl design for the front glass of his company and another one for the glass of his interior desk

how can we price these?

Can you give me please detailed **pricing list** (maximum and minimum)?
regardless of the rent of the office, the number of employees etc...
only design price for a small experience lets say freelancer an I will edit the prices to be usable for the company

Thank you, best regards

Note: this is our first experience so we are new to this

Comment: Hi Rayane, welcome to GDSE. Nobody will be able to give you any relevant pricing without a lot more information. Pricing will vary hugely by location to begin with. Your personal circumstances, business model, expenses, experience etc all factor in to your pricing. There are a lot of previous questions about pricing methods you can read through: [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/957/52050), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18142/52050) and [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/graphic-design-pricing) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't copy other people's pricing that's not going to work for you long term. You need to work out what it will cost you to produce the elements for the client for example...

If you have a team of people, working in an office you'll need to charge a lot more as your overheads are higher e.g. paying rent for the office, paying your team.

If you work on your own from home then you don't have that expense, but maybe you have another cost to consider. You also need to work out how long it will take you to complete the job? If you can complete the job in 10 working hours and you charge $10 an hour then that's $100.

It's up to you to work it out based on your situation and skill.

Comment: Thank you, regardless of the rent and the number of employees, I need to know the minimum and maximum pricing of the elements I mentioned, what does a brochure design costs (minimum and maximum) etc..

Comment: @Rayane sky is the limit for maximum.

Comment: I think his question is good in the aspect of he is trying to see what would be the minimum to charge. We as a professionals, should hold a value, and not to undervalue the whole industry and other professionals in your area. It hugely depends on your location and experience of your service.