# what are "PSD to HTML" Jobs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, html

I'm a graphic designer usually do logo and banner design work. I recently got a work from my client to make PSD's for the website. So i want to ask that what exactly he will be expecting from me? I don't have a strong knowledge of html/css.

Comment: I'd actually ask the client to specify everything that I'm unsure about what he wants me to do. Sometimes clients use words they don't understand. I'm not saying this is the case here, but you'll know if you ask.

Comment: Many web sites don't even use PSD files as a basis any longer. It's often faster and easier to go straight to HTML/CSS markup.

Answer (score 4):

PSD to HTML is the non-preferred way to go about designing and building web sites. The process is very waterfall-based. It's essentially:

- Visual designer lays out everything in PhotoShop
- Client approves it, then tosses the PSD over the fence to the dev team and says "deal with it"
- Dev team "deals with it" and typically produces a bloated web site with poor interaction (and not necessarily their fault).

The problem with this process is that PhotoShop is not a dynamic canvas--but your web site is. A web page can be viewed in any number of web browsers, on any number of devices, on any number of differently sized screens, with any number of installed fonts, with any number of interactive inputs. PhotoShop can't really accommodate any of that properly.

The better way to handle it is to design with the code in mind from day one. This is more of an Agile process.

All that said, if the client has asked you to create the PSDs, then go for it. You have the easy part. Unfortunately, there will be some developer down stream that will hate you for it, but by then hopefully you've gotten your money and ran. :)

Comment: Funny answer. :o)

Answer (score 1):

PSD to HTML means that you are going to convert PSD into HTML. Give them working HTML + CSS + JAVASCRIPT. But if the client gave you a job to create PSD for the website, as per your question, all you need to do is create a PSD and let somebody else do the conversion.

Comment: so its just an idea that i'll be giving to them. Does layers are of any importance here? I mean can i even design in the coreldraw as well(I'm better on it)?

Comment: Depending on the developer that is going to work with it later, I prefer layered photoshop, some developers don't use Photoshop so JPEG or PNG will suffice. Also you might need to cut the JPEG/PNG depending on your design.

Comment: @Ahmed: About your question on what to charge: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/959/306

Answer (score -8):

Take that job and make a good looking webdesign in Photoshop, then send me the PSDs doc , i'll convert them into HTML CSS as I am expert in this field. Contact me at Skype my id is arlalsaehl . you and me can make a team. Thanks.