# What should be included in a PSD to convert it into HTML?CSS code

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css, html

I'm working for the first time on "PSD to HTML" job for a client(i usually do logos and banner work). As this is my first time, i'm quite confused about "What should exactly be in the PSD file". Should it have a complete look of the website? or just the structure of the site? Should i add photos,logo,icons and all that stuff with separate layers in the PSD?

Kindly help me about this confusion.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine unless they specifically ask for a wireframe, they want you to design the finished look of the site. Yes you should include all proposed final assets, as you visually see the final result.

You should give them some work in progress updates though. As polishing images can take a lot of work, you don't want to head too far in the wrong direction for the client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're only doing the design and not the actual implementation? In that case, PSD to HTML generally means that you need to provide the developer with all the assets and details they will need to actually convert your design into HTML.

Absolutely yes, it should have the complete, final, polished design of the site, but depending on your client and their dev, you might want to also include the site structure to make it clear where each link points to.

Putting all the photos, logos, icons, etc. on separate layers (preferably grouped appropriately for clarity) would come in very handy for any future design work, whether done by you or another designer, but you should probably check with your client as the developer might also want you to export all the assets out of the PSD. Including a list of all the fonts and colours used for elements such as the background or font colours and so on will also be very helpful for the dev and make sure that your design is implemented as closely as possible to what you envisioned.

Comment: great! yes, i'm doing only the psd not implementation.
do you have idea how much should i charge for this job?

Comment: @Ahmed Hard to say... I don't know the going rate where you're at, but a quick search turned up this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all of the assets (icons, images, etc), I prefer when other designers give me a list of fonts, font sizes, and font weights and the the amount of white space between main elements. Giving white space in pixels is important to help make sure the finished product matches the mockup as closely as possible.