# Rates for UI design - On what basis should I charge?

Tags: website-design, website-templates

This is my first freelance work. Can somebody tell me that on what basis should I fix my rates for this home page design coz I am not able to decide. The client wanted in green and red combination. I have designed the whole UI in photoshop. Logo is also designed by me. Please give reviews and feedback. Should i fix my rates on time taken, or on the quantity of work or on my experience....???

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help with pricing because it varies depending on country and other variables. But check this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services

Comment: If you were looking for some design feedback, I'd consider a different green. That one you have is rather hard on the eyes.

Comment: @DA01 I agree, perhaps a slightly softer green.

Comment: Thank you DA01 and Mathew....for the feedback. I will surely work on it. :)