# How much is the average cost of 1 hour of graphic design in Miami, FL USA?

Tags: website-design, business

I have a potential client from USA, and I live in another country. I would like to know (an average price in dollars), how much a graphic/web designer would charge per hour for maintaining the website (the website is already done). I hope you can help me!

Regards!

Comment: USA is a pretty big place i would expect the cost to vary wildly.

Comment: If it helps you out, Miami is the place

Comment: Nobody will be able to give you a reasonably objective answer without knowing your personal circumstances, business model etc. An average price is useless. The answer here is very appropriate: [What price should I charge for design services?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services)

Comment: @CAI I think that second link is more relevant for closing this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Johannes I agree. I only found it after linking the other one

Comment: Location, education, experience, desire to do job, what's involved in the job, additional purchases (stock images, fonts), etc. all influence the price. This question is simply too broad to give a good answer to. CAI's links are good links to follow for coming up with numbers. At the end of the day it needs to be a number you're happy with otherwise the job probably isn't worth doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Bureau of Labor Statistics the Average Hourly Wage for a **full-time** Graphic Designer in Miami, FL is $20.68

Source: http://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes_33124.htm

For a contract you should expect to pay at least double if not triple that. They have to support their overhead, taxes, insurance, and make enough profit to still live. When I lived in Miami I started negotiations around $60/hr.

This is for **Graphic Design**. If you're hiring someone to do coding then it will go up substantially well into the $100/hr range.