# How do I charge for editing client work?

Tags: client-relations, designers, business, pricing

A regular client operates a restaurant and I’ve designed ads for them.

Often these ads need tweaking: promotions, sale etc. How do I best determine a way to charge them?

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, charge my hourly rate for **edits** to existing pieces.

If you don't know your hourly rate... [figure it out](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/959/3270).

Answer (score 1):

A regular client will have requests ranging from 10 minutes to a few hours, or more. Just keep a timesheet for all these requests, 3 columns: date, how much time, what the request was. At the end of the period, charge for the accumulated hours, multiplied by your hourly rate.

Use the remaining time for other clients. Keep more timesheets. If your work is good, increase your hourly rate with every new client.

In time, you will begin to appreciate more the clients willing to pay the highest hourly rate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of two methods.

**Hourly payment.** Calculate how much your work costs in one hour and estimate in hours when a client tells you to make edits. This is an easier way because it takes less time to calculate and allows you to manage your finances more easily.

**Payment for work.** Write the price of your services for each completed task. Add criteria such as the complexity of the work, the number of repetitions, additional resources, etc.
You can show this price at the beginning of work on the project and indicate what work will be performed, which may be additional, and which may be in an exceptional case.